# Creating a Gridview for a word search

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

I am trying to create a word search using a gridview but I'm unsure how to add rows from a JSONArray, but my app keeps crashing at this point and also at            `gridView.addView(tableRow);`

This is my new puzzle class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class NewPuzzleActivity extends Activity implements OnRetrieveHTTPData {

    //word search data
    String[] rows;
    String[] words;
    char[] letters;

    //variables for the grid creation
    int letterID = 0;
    int rowID = 0;

    //found words by the user
    String[] wordsFound;
    int[] rowFound;
    int[] columnFound;
    int[]directionFound;

    // objects within the game *miscellaneous properties*
    boolean firstLetterSelected = false;
    int numOFLettersSelected = 0;
    int[] lettersSelected;
    int[] rowsSelected;
    int[] columnsSelected;
    String selectedString = "";
    int directionSelected = 0;
    int lastLetterSelected = -1;
    String date;

    GridView gridView;
    TextView textView;
    Toast toast;

    public NewPuzzleActivity(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.hasExtra("rows")){
            // initialize the data
            rows = intent.getExtras().getStringArray("rows");
            addRows();
            stringArrayToCharArray();
            fillGrid();

            lettersSelected = new int[rows.length];
            rowsSelected = new int[rows.length];
            columnsSelected = new int[rows.length];
        }
        if(intent.hasExtra("words")){
            words = intent.getExtras().getStringArray("words");

            wordsFound = new String[words.length];
            rowFound = new int[words.length];
            columnFound = new int[words.length];
            directionFound = new int[words.length];

            fillWords();
        }
        if(intent.hasExtra("date")){
            date = intent.getExtras().getString("date");

            //textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Title);
            //textView.append(date);
        }
    }

    public void letterButonClick(View view){
        if(toast != null){
            toast.cancel(); // cancel toast message to prevent multiple toast messages
        }

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(view.getId());
        textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        //works out the column number of the selected letter(s)
        columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] = (Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())% rows.length);
        if(columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] == 0) columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] = rows.length;
        //works out the row number of the selected letter(s)
        rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] = (Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())/ rows.length)+1;
        if(rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] == 0) rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] = rows.length;
        //fixes the last column
        if(columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] == rows.length) rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]-=1;

        lettersSelected[numOFLettersSelected] = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()) + 4999;

        Log.i("Selected Column", Integer.toString(columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]));
        Log.i("Selected Row", Integer.toString(rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]));

        if(!firstLetterSelected){
            firstLetterSelected = true;
            //resets the selected string
            selectedString = textView1.getText().toString();
            numOFLettersSelected = 1;
        }else{
            //adds letters to selected string
            selectedString += textView1.getText().toString();

            //compares to the last letter to work out the direction
            if(columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] +1 == columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected - 1] &&
                    rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] +1 == rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected - 1]){
                //direction left / down
                directionSelected = 0;
                Log.i("Direction", "0");
                checkWordFound();
            }
            else if(rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]+1 == rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]&&
                    columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] == columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]){
                //direction is down
                directionSelected = 1;
                Log.i("Direction", "1");
                checkWordFound();
            }
            else if(columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] - 1 == columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1] &&
                    rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]+1 == rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]){
                //direction is right-down
                directionSelected = 2;
                Log.i("Direction", "2");
                checkWordFound();
            }
            else if(columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]+1 == columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]&&
                    rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] == rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]){
                //direction is left
                directionSelected = 3;
                Log.i("Direction", "3");
                checkWordFound();
            }
            else if(columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]-1 == columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]&&
                    rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] == rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]){
                //direction is right
                directionSelected = 4;
                Log.i("Direction", "4");
                checkWordFound();
            }
            else if(columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]+1 == columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1] &&
                    rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]-1 == rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]){
                //direction is left-up
                directionSelected = 5;
                Log.i("Direction", "5");
                checkWordFound();
            }
            else if(rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]-1 == rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]&&
                    columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected] == columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]){
                //direction is up
                directionSelected = 6;
                Log.i("Direction", "6");
                checkWordFound();
            }
            else if(columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]-1 == columnsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1] &&
                    rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected]-1 == rowsSelected[numOFLettersSelected-1]) {
                //direction is right-up
                directionSelected = 7;
                Log.i("Direction", "7");
                checkWordFound();
            }else{
                // not a letter within/ around the the first letter selected, reset any selected letters

                //deselect words and select a new letter to starr again
                //selected string reset
                selectedString = textView1.getText().toString();

                for(int i : lettersSelected){
                    try{
                        TextView letters = (TextView)findViewById(i);
                        letters.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        i++;
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        //break
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                //variables reset
                directionSelected = -1;
                numOFLettersSelected = 0;
                lettersSelected = new int[rows.length];
                rowsSelected = new int[rows.length];
                columnsSelected = new int[rows.length];

                // new letter to be selected
                columnsSelected[0] = (Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())% rows.length);
                if(columnsSelected[0] == 0) columnsSelected[0] = rows.length;

                rowsSelected[0] = (Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()) / rows.length)+1;
                if(rowsSelected[0] == 0) rowsSelected[0] = rows.length;
                if(columnsSelected[0] == rows.length) rowsSelected[0] -= 1;
                lettersSelected[0] = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()) + 4999;

                textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            numOFLettersSelected++;
            Log.i("Selected TEXT", selectedString);
        }

        lastLetterSelected = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
    }

    private void fillGrid(){
        int LetterChars = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < rows.length * rows.length; i++){
            if(LetterChars >= rows.length){
                rowID--;
                LetterChars = 0;
            }

            addLetter((TableRow)findViewById(rowID+4000+ rows.length-1));
            TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(i+5000);
            textView1.setText(Character.toString(letters[i]));
            LetterChars++;
        }
    }

    private void fillWords(){
        for(int i = 1; i < rows.length -1; i++){
            String name = "Word"+i;
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
            if(id != 0){
                TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(id);
                try{
                    textView1.setText(words[i-1]);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    textView1.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void stringArrayToCharArray(){
        char[] chars = new char[rows.length * rows.length];

        int i = 0;
        //selection of strings
        for(int j = 0; j< rows.length; j++){
            // selection of letters
            for(int k = 0; k < rows.length; k++){
                try{
                    chars[i] = rows[j].charAt(k);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error", "Error when adding chars");
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        letters = chars;
    }

    private void addLetter(TableRow row){

        TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
        textView1.setId(letterID+5000);
        textView1.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        textView1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25);

        TableRow.LayoutParams textLayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        textLayout.setMargins(10,0,0,10);

        textView1.setTextAlignment(textView1.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        textView1.setTag(""+(letterID+1));

        textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                letterButonClick(v);
            }
        });

        textView1.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            //draggin selection *To be implemented*
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        textView1.setLayoutParams(textLayout);

        row.addView(textView1);
        letterID++;
    }

    private void addRows(){
        for(int i= 0; i < rows.length;i++){
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setId(i+4000);
            gridView.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }

    private void checkWordFound(){

        int foundID = 0;

        for(String w: words){
            if(selectedString.contains(w)){
                //word that have been found
                Log.i("Word Found", "Found: " + w);

                //highlight words that have been found in the word list
                for(int i = 1; i < rows.length-1; i++){
                    String name = "Word"+i;
                    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
                    if(id != 0){
                        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(id);
                        try{
                            if(textView1.getText().equals(w)){
                                //textview that contains the found words
                                textView1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                //add to found
                wordsFound[foundID] =w;
                columnFound[foundID] = columnsSelected[0];
                rowFound[foundID] = rowsSelected[0];
                directionFound[foundID] = directionSelected;

                //variables reset
                directionSelected = -1;
                numOFLettersSelected = 0;
                lettersSelected = new int[rows.length];
                rowsSelected = new int[rows.length];
                columnsSelected = new int[rows.length];
            }
            foundID++;
        }
        checkCompletion();
        //no words are found
    }

    private void checkCompletion(){
        if(Arrays.equals(words, wordsFound)){

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Word Search Complete")
                    .setMessage("Submit Score?")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //submit score
                            submitResults();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    }

    public void homeClicked(View v){
        finish();
    }

    public void submitResults(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onRetrieveTaskCompleted(String httpData) {
        Log.i("Solution Response", responseData);
        //debug toasts
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),("Solution Submitted"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

error log

```
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-04 00:49:18.929    6068-6068/sl.lloyd.steve.angrywordsearchthefinalone D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-04 00:49:18.937    6068-6068/sl.lloyd.steve.angrywordsearchthefinalone E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sl.lloyd.steve.angrywordsearchthefinalone, PID: 6068
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sl.lloyd.steve.angrywordsearchthefinalone/sl.lloyd.steve.angrywordsearchthefinalone.NewPuzzleActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
            at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:461)
            at sl.lloyd.steve.angrywordsearchthefinalone.NewPuzzleActivity.addRows(NewPuzzleActivity.java:320)
            at sl.lloyd.steve.angrywordsearchthefinalone.NewPuzzleActivity.onCreate(NewPuzzleActivity.java:75)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Could you add the error that you're getting when the app crashes?

Comment: Ive added the errors that are being displayed in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot `addView(view)` directly to [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), because it is an `AdapterView` which does not allow that. So you have to do this operation in your `Adapter`. You just have to add more data to the adapter and after call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, so your `GridView` will be added the `View` by itself.